# Family of solution plot does not agree with slope field plot

Tags: plotting

I plotted a few members of a family of solutions

```
Table[Plot[C (x^2 + 1), {x, -4, 4}], {C, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

However, when I try to plot the slope field I get a completely different morphology of the system. This may be a small error, but I cannot find it.

```
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + 1
p2 = StreamPlot[{1, g[x, y]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 100}, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, 
  StreamPoints -> {{{{-1, 3}, Red}, {{3, 3}, Green}, Automatic}}, 
  StreamColorFunction -> None]
```

Any hints on what has happened?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a little bit of misunderstanding `g[x_, y_] := x^2 + 1` represents the slope. Not the solution your were trying to plot.

i.e. the ode is of this form $y'=g(x,y)$. You can not plot $g(x,y)$ and expect it to match the solution of $y(x)$ itself.

In order to do what you want, you can do the following. First solve the ode analytically, and the solution will have a constant of integration. Now you can vary this constant and you will get same plots as the `StreamPlot`

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y'[x] == x^2 + 1;
sol = DSolveValue[ode, y[x], x];
Table[Plot[sol /. C[1] -> c, {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {-30, 30}], {c, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. better not use `C` as this is protected symbol.

Comment: Thanks for this, so the slope field is correctly printed?

Comment: @Vangsnes Yes, it is correct. For different `C` you will get different curve. You just need to find the correct `C` value to get the curves with the red color you have.